# Parsing JSON blob dump in HTTP POST in PHP

Tags: php, json

one of the application is sending a webhook callback as HTTP Post, from which I need to parse a JSON blob dump (custom_fields in the below URL). Here is one such POST from a server application:

http://localhost/webhook/?unit_price=0.00&currency=Free&buyer_name=Shivraj&payment_id=34565c17000F04251234&custom_fields=%7B%22Field_87630%22%3A+%7B%22value%22%3A+%22uname1%22%2C+%22label%22%3A+%22user_name%22%2C+%22required%22%3A+%22on%22%2C+%22type%22%3A+%22char%22%7D%2C+%22Field_63520%22%3A+%7B%22value%22%3A+%221234%22%2C+%22label%22%3A+%22auction_id%22%2C+%22required%22%3A+true%2C+%22type%22%3A+%22char%22%7D%2C+%22Field_76855%22%3A+%7B%22value%22%3A+%22tx1%22%2C+%22label%22%3A+%22tx_type%22%2C+%22required%22%3A+%22on%22%2C+%22type%22%3A+%22char%22%7D%7D&amount=10.00&fees=0.00&status=Credit&quantity=1

In my code:

```
$custom_fields= json_decode($_REQUEST['custom_fields'], true);
$f1 = $custom_fields['Field_63520']['value'];
$f2 = $custom_fields['Field_87630']['value'];
$f3 = $custom_fields['Field_76855']['value'];
```

I get error/warning,

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'Field_63520' in webhook.php on line 70
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'value' in webhook.php on line 70
...
f1:{
f2:{
f3:{
```

when I print the $custom_fields, I get:

```
{\"Field_87630\": {\"value\": \"uname1\", \"label\": \"user_name\", \"required\": \"on\", \"type\": \"char\"}, \"Field_63520\": {\"value\": \"1234\", \"label\": \"auction_id\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"char\"}, \"Field_76855\": {\"value\": \"tx1\", \"label\": \"tx_type\", \"required\": \"on\", \"type\": \"char\"}}
```

I am kind of stuck here without knowing how to proceed. Any suggestions would help. Thanks.

Comment: please print your decoded array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `backslash` from your `JSON` data. Use `stripslashes()` function to remove `backslash`

Your code should be :

```
<?php
$custom_fields = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['custom_fields']),true);
$f1 = $custom_fields['Field_63520']['value'];
$f2 = $custom_fields['Field_87630']['value'];
$f3 = $custom_fields['Field_76855']['value'];
?>
```